# GDK events handling without GTK

Tags: python, glib, gdk

I'm programming (in python) GDK without GTK, simply as a x11 abstraction. THIS POST IS MY LAST CHANCE.

My problem is that I don't know how capture the GDK window's signals/events or what are their names.

When I do:

```
window = gdk.Window(
            gdk.get_default_root_window(),
            width=400,
            height=200,
            window_type=gdk.WINDOW_CHILD,
            wclass=gdk.INPUT_OUTPUT,
            event_mask=gdk.KEY_PRESS_MASK | gdk.MOTION_NOTIFY | gdk.EXPOSURE_MASK)

window.connect("key_press_event", on_key)
```

I get:

```
unknown signal name: key_press_event
```

GTK and PYGTK references talk about classes, functions and constants but nothing about their interrelation so they don't help.
Is it about glib main loop?

I need some examples. Any good GDK tutorial or source code? Any glib.MainLoop example for capturing GDK signals?

Thank you.

Comment: Noctis Skytower, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gdk_event_handler_set to set the event handler (which is also the function used by gtk). Don't know which python binding u r using but I think you can easily find the corresponding python function. (In gi, it's simply Gdk.Event.handler_set)

You can check [here](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=3998) for an example (There is also a non-block example). Although they are in C.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to connect to `key-press-event`, which is a `gtk.Widget` signal. `gdk.Window` doesn't inherit from `gtk.Widget`, so it doesn't have that signal.

In the GTK documentation, the little sections near the top labeled "Object Hierarchy" tell you how the classes relate together. There isn't really such thing as a GDK tutorial since one hardly ever uses it without GTK. I don't think it's very useful to do so either. Perhaps you can elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?